# Why do I get the error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" when I deploy my mvc application to a live server using iis?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, excel-interop

I'm uploading an excel file however and trying to read its contents. With the following code, it works fine on localhost. However if I upload to a live server using IIS, it doesn't work. The strange thing is, my uploaded file does save to the content folder on the server, however in the error message it looks to open the file from my local computer :

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad) +0
   Twilio4.Controllers.HomeController.Import(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile, SendMessageVal Model)

in C:\Users\sbudhai\source\repos\SAP\SAP\Controllers\HomeController.cs:111

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile, SendMessageVal Model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        if (excelfile == null || excelfile.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Error2 = "Please select an excel file <br>";
            return View(Model);
        }
        else
        {
            if (excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx") || excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xls"))
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                excelfile.SaveAs(path);

                //Read data from excel file 
                Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                List<NUMBER> listProducts = new List<NUMBER>();
                var C = range.Rows.Count;
                var B = range.Rows.Count;

                C++;
                for (int row = 2; row < C; row++)
                {
                    NUMBER p = new NUMBER();
                    p.NUMBER1 = long.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
                    listProducts.Add(p);
                }

                ViewBag.ListProducts = listProducts;
                workbook.Close(path);
                return View("Confirm", listProducts);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "File type is incorrect <br>";
                return View(Model);
            }

        }
    }
    else
    { 
        return View(Model);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks` means you're trying to start Excel and control it from your code. This won't work unless Excel in installed on the server. Even then, it's an awful idea as each request will start a *different* Excel instance. Your code forgets to close Excel which means the server will start one Excel instance for every request

Comment: If you want to read files use a library like EPPlus, the Open XML SDK or even the Jet OLEDB provider. Don't install Excel on the server. Dont' worry about the obsolete `xls` format either, it was abandoned 12 years ago. All Excel versions since 2007 produce `xlsx` files.

Comment: It looks like you intend to support .xls files? If you don't need to it would be much easier to support .xlsx only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! I will definitely look into Open XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Office Interop on a server is [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

The linked article describes some of the problems you will face.  I would recommend using an alternative such as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), or a commercial product such as [Aspose Cells](https://products.aspose.com/cells).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know it was not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenXML library instead of Office Interop, you will spend time trying to fix it but in the end this is much better

Answer (score 0):

As per [this Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d6c383a-94eb-4898-9d22-aa4bb69be25b/excel-interop-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x800a03ec-microsoft-office-excel?forum=vbgeneral) post you may need to create the folder:

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop " (for 64 bit Windows)

or

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop " (for 32 bit Windows)

and set Full control permissions for the user who will be accessing it (for example in Win7 & IIS 7 & DefaultAppPool set the permissions for user "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool")